# Add <div> tags dynamically according to the no. of values in database

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, dynamic, struts2

I have a form with remarks and attachments details. Initially the details are send from A to B requesting for files (attachments)  then B sends the requested files to A. If A finds the files wrong he sends it back to B requesting to change files. Now this process goes to and fro unless A accepts the files. By the end of the cycle I have to display all the documents & remarks associated with them date wise. As the no.of files & remarks are not fixed I am not sure how to implement it.

JSP:

```
    <div id="AttachDoc">
      Attached Documents:

    </div>
```

I used jquery to display attached files :

```
function viewDetails(trans_id){      
        $.ajax({
          type:'POST',
          url: '<s:url action="viewTransDetails"/>',
          data: {TransID: trans_id},
          dataType: 'json',              
          success: function(getValue){                      
              $('#AttachDoc ol').remove();

               var data = JSON.stringify(getValue.FileName);                   
               var json = JSON.parse(data);  


               for(var i=0 ; i<json1.length; i++){          
                      $('#AttachDoc').append('<ol><a href="downloadAttach.action?attachFileName='+getValue.FileName[i]+'">'+getValue.FileName[i]+'</a></ol>');
                }              
       });     
  }
```

action()

```
try{
        currentCon = ConnectionManager.getConnection();
        Statement stmt = (Statement) currentCon.createStatement();
         rs=stmt.executeQuery("SELECT doc_name FROM trans_attach WHERE trans_id='"+trans_id+"'");
        while(rs.next()){
            FileName.add(rs.getString("doc_name")); 
            trns_details.setFileName(FileName);
        }
```

This displays all the attachments in the div. But I have to display the remarks(with date) followed by attachment names. How to do that?
Thanks In Advance.

Comment: Iterate over them and emit a div for each one?

Comment: ya something like that.